# How to make a strikethrough look like an x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a page that uses only jquery to make tabs, not jQuery UI. At the top of the page there is an `h1`, like this:

```html
<h1>Jquery <del>UI</del> Tabs</h1>
```

I want to know if I can make the strikethrough look like an x, like this:

Comment: You want it to look like an "x", like what?

Comment: @Jonathan: I think the OP means to cross out the text with two diagonal lines instead of one horizontal line.

Comment: An x per character, or an x across the whole line, or a whole line of x's? Poster wrote "like this:" and didn't provide anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this using CSS:

```css
del {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}
del:before {
    color: #000;
    content: 'X';
    display: block;
    font-family: "arial";
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Jquery <del>UI</del> Tabs</h1>
```

Essentially all it does it place an "X" on top of the text using the `:before` sudo selector.